# How can I use gensim keyedvectors to find the connecting words between two given words?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

With gensim, I can solve the equation "king + woman - man = queen" with this line:

```py
model.most_similar_cosmul(positive=['king', 'woman'], negative=['man'])
```

But how can I pass in `('king', 'queen')` and output an interpolation like this:

```
positive=['woman'], negative=['man']
```

It would be awesome to pass in two dissimilar words like "rain" and "mouse" to see what words need to be added/subtracted to transform one into the other!

If gensim can't do this, are there any tools for this?

Comment: This is interesting.